# Saving each user's file along with corresponding database / table

Tags: c#, .net, sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

**CONTEXT**: I am writing an application in Visual C# / .Net, where the user can:

- Create a new document-file "Untitled.abc"
- Add some data/content, e.g., images, text, etc.
- Save the document-file as "MyDoc7.abc", where abc would be my app-specific extension.

**QUESTION**: Is the following method good to implement the above, or is there a simpler/cleaner approach?

- I start with a SQL-Server database called MyDb.
- Each time a user creates a new document-file, I programatically add a new DB table to MyDb
- The newly created DB table stores the data/content from just that particular corresponding document-file created by the user.
- When user re-opens the saved document-file in the future, I programatically read the data/content from the attached corresponding DB table.

**UPDATE**:
Solved. I will be using this Alternative approach:

- I start with a SQL-Server database called MyDb with a table called MyTable, including a column called FileId.
- Each time a user creates a new document-file, I assign the file a unique id, e.g., FileId = 5.
- When the user adds a piece of data/content to the file, I store the piece of data to MyTable, but also store FileId = 5 for that piece of data.
- In the future, when the user re-opens the file, I fetch all pieces of data from MyTable where FileId = 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a particularly bad idea to do that.

1. You don't want to create tables on the fly
2. If all the data is in the database, what is the file for?

I would rather choose the approach that Office uses:

1. The file really is a zip archive which contains:

   1. A folder for the assets (images and the like)
   2. The actual file with the content and relative links to the assets.

Comment: OK, but here is the situation: The database is for storing the data (let's say for simplicity, it's a list of friend-names). On the other hand, the saved "document-file" is to save that data PLUS some parameters, e.g., FRIENDS_LIST_DISPLAY_STYLE = Horizontal. More generally, I intend the document-file to be a user-friendly way of pulling up their own particular data. Does that make sense?

Comment: I can go along with the approach that Office uses, but in my case, it's actual data that has to be structurally stored in database format, not just images/plain-text. What is an approach I might use in that case?

Comment: In that case you still wouldn't want to create a new table every time. Maybe a document database (NoSQL) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. However, before I jump into learning NoSQL, what do you think about the Alternative approach I added now to the Question? (The "Update" approach will not create databases/tables on the fly.)

Comment: @boardbite: I am not sure you want to store everything in *one* table either, but the unique ID per file is good. It might be better to have one table for assets and one for content so you can give each table only the columns it needs.

Comment: That's even better! Gonna give it a shot.